# how to determine if Java heap is using compressed pointers and whether or not resides at address 0 in memory?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, garbage-collection, jvm, heap-memory

I am trying to follow up on some tips in this blog https://www.elastic.co/blog/a-heap-of-trouble#ref5 which discusses the benefits of sizing one's Java heap so that (a) compressed pointers can be used (for heaps under 32GB) and (b) so that the heap resides at address 0 in memory.  The article details how compressed pointers allow more efficient  use of heap space, and explains that when the heap lives at address zero this  reduces the amount of arithmetic necessary to resolve pointer addresses.    Finally, the article says that if I use JVM options `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions` -`XX:+PrintCompressedOopsMode` I will see log output either like this:

`heap address: 0x000000011be00000, size: 27648 MB, zero based Compressed Oops`

which indicates zero-based compressed oops are enabled, or output like this

`heap address: 0x0000000118400000, size: 28672 MB, Compressed Oops with base: 0x00000001183ff000`

Which indicates that the heap begins at an address other than zero, therefore requiring the aforementioned increase amount of arithmetic processing.

However, when I tried those options and grep'd through my application's (Elastic Search's) log directory I could find no such messages. If anyone could advise me on how I can force details of zero-based (or not zero based) compressed pointers to be logged I'd be very grateful.

RESOLUTION:

great answers !.. I accepted @apangin's and I wrapped the java program he provided in a shell script that can run as long as you have java.. which you should if you are looking at Java heap!  here is the script: https://github.com/buildlackey/scripts/blob/master/verify_compressed_pointers_from_zero_offset.sh

Comment: Note that the heap doesn’t start at zero in both cases. But in the first case, the sum of start address and heap size is below the 32GiB threshold, which allows zero based addressing. But why is this question tagged with “garbage-collection”?

Comment: Please provide information about your OS and ES version, if my answer did not help you.

Comment: Wow.. great answers. I will review and try out the suggestions tomorrow.  In response to  @Holger - reason for the tag garbage collection is cause we are trying to optimize the setting of our heap size in addition to other garbage collection related tweaks.. thought this topic is relevant for any one else tuning GC.  /thnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[HotSpot Serviceability Agent](http://www.javamagazine.mozaicreader.com/JanFeb2017#&pageSet=31&page=0&contentItem=0) can show this on a running JVM process even with no extra command-line flags required.

Run the following program with the target Java process ID as an argument.

```
import sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VM;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool;

public class CompressedOopsInfo extends Tool {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        VM vm = VM.getVM();
        System.out.println("CompressedOops = " + vm.isCompressedOopsEnabled());
        System.out.println("CompressedClassPointers = " + vm.isCompressedKlassPointersEnabled());
        System.out.println("OOP base = 0x" + Long.toHexString(vm.getDebugger().getNarrowOopBase()));
        System.out.println("OOP shift = " + vm.getDebugger().getNarrowOopShift());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CompressedOopsInfo().execute(args);
    }
}
```

Prior to JDK 9 this requires including `${JDK_HOME}/lib/sa-jdi.jar` in the classpath. The program needs to run under the same JVM version as used to run the target process.

Answer (score 5):

Assume you are using Linux and ES with version 5.x and higher.

The most efficient way to gather information across the whole cluster is to use [the nodes info API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-nodes-info.html):

> curl -XGET
>   "http://localhost:9200/_nodes/jvm?filter_path=nodes.*.jvm.using_compressed_ordinary_object_pointers"
>
> {"nodes":{"-jYDCxbpT2SBKc4dTfOYsA":{"jvm":{"using_compressed_ordinary_object_pointers":"true"}}}}

The same information is logged into the main log - /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log

> [2017-10-06T23:03:15,223][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [-jYDCxb]
>   heap size [1.9gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]

If you are interested in the real JVM output then you have to know that by default JVM writes it's messages into standard output and on Linux distributions this output by default is configured to redirect to journalctl. So you have two choices. The first one is to read the journalctl:

> sudo journalctl -u elasticsearch.service
>
> Narrow klass base: 0x0000000000000000, Narrow klass shift: 3
>   Compressed class space size: 1073741824 Address: 0x0000000100000000 Req Addr: 0x0000000100000000

But sometimes journalctl disabled by default and you have to change this setting in the daemon config `/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service` by removing `--quite` parameter from ES command line parameters. The second approach is the simplest and cross platform - redirect JVM message to particular GC log output:

> -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintCompressedOopsMode -Xloggc:/tmp/vm.log

Now you can see all GC related output in `/tmp/vm.log`

Answer (score 1):

> However, when I tried those options and grep'd through my application's (Elastic Search's) log directory I could find no such messages.

Probably because it only logs application messages to that directory. You need to log JVM output to a file too or inspect stdout or stderr for those messages.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean compressedOopsEnabled = Boolean.parseBoolean(java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
    .getPlatformMXBean(com.sun.management.HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.class)
    .getVMOption("UseCompressedOops").getValue());
```